# TTransportException when trying to connect HBase in WAN

Tags: python, hbase

I'm trying to insert data to HBase using python. I use happybase and when I tested on the same machine on which HBase ran, it worked. And it worked on a machine in the same LAN as HBase machine as well. However, when I tried to use the similar scheme in WAN, I got a TTransportException. Do I need to do some configuration? Anyone could help me? Thanks for your help:)

---

update:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    conn, batch = connect_to_hbase(host, namespace, table_name, batch_size)
  File "test.py", line 6, in connect_to_hbase
table_prefix_separator=":")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 176, in open
    self.transport.open()
  File "thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx", line 34, in thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.open (thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1383)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 104, in open
    message="Could not connect to %s" % str(addr))
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(message="Could not connect to ('125.141.200.35', 9090)", type=1)
```

Comment: add the stacktrace.

Comment: added, hope it will help..